# Expo monorepo with react-navigation

Tags: jestjs, expo, hadoop-yarn, monorepo

I have tried to create a monorepo containing two Expo apps using React Navigation with different SDK levels and I forced it to use `nohoist` for all

```json
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": ["apps/*"],
    "nohoist": ["**/**" ]
  },
```

The apps themselves work, but the jest tests fails due to

```
  The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner)> component:

          at theme (C:\dh\expo-49\apps\playground\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\NavigationContainer.tsx:55:5)
          at children (C:\dh\expo-49\apps\playground\src\navigation\InstrumentedNavigationContainer\index.tsx:14:3)
          at App (C:\dh\expo-49\apps\playground\src\App.tsx:10:50)

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

     Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

       6 |
       7 | it("should load", async () => {
    >  8 |   render(<App />);
```

Individually they work.  If I remove one whole app it also works.

I can see in my root node modules it is empty except for lefthook and commitlint plus two sym links for the packages.  Also if I remove the `NavigationContainer` from the other app the jest tests work.

My question is there something else that may be causing that

> Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

I am thinking maybe it is because of

```
   at Object.invariant (node_modules/@react-navigation/native/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:181:3)
```

which sows that there's another react-native inside `@react-navigation/native`